# Angular - Observable or Subject for DataSource

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have an Angular 7 application with Mat Tables retrieving data from API. I have assigned dynamic pagination values, that is pageSizeOptions value will be getting changed whenever I load grid based on some dropdown value and by default all the records will be getting displayed.

If API returns 23 records, then pageSizeOptions will have 10,20,23,30,40,50 and by default it will display all 23 records. When next time I change dropdown value, API returns 45 records but this time still my grid displays only 23 records eventhough pageSizeOptions has 10,20,30,40,45,50 and selection shows 45 as selected.

I assume this is due to View/Grid loaded before pageSizeOptions value is assigned since API takes some time to return data. I thought of resolving this issue by implementing Observable/subscribe.

I am not sure, how to implement these for pageSizeOptions. Can someone please help me to resolve this.

```
let gridData = responseStudents.Students.map(item => new ResponseStudents());
this.myDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(gridData);
this.Count = gridData.length;
this.PageSizeOptions = [this.Count, 5, 10, 25, 100, 500];
//To remove duplicate
this.PageSizeOptions = Array.from(this.PageSizeOptions.reduce((m, t) => m.set(t, t), new Map()).values());
```

Comment: Do you use `MatTableDataSource` for binding data to mat-table? Can you please add the code where you assign results of API call to mat-table data? And also can you please add the template code for `mat-table`?

Comment: @ysf - I've added the code in second line. API takes some time to return data but before that paginator values are loaded in UI.

Comment: If **iamaword**'s answer doesn't solve your problem I need to see whole component and template code. You need to make sure that you assign the paginator to new datasource as **iamaword** stated. If it is not solving your problem then it must be something else, probably related to your logic. It is impossible to guess from the code piece you shared above. Again, please do not hesitate to share your whole component and template code.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rabwf2?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html) that may accomplish the foundation of what you are looking for. There ended up being some issues with actually refreshing the table when it came to pagination updates done via the component file, so I opted to change the dataSource.

You should essentially be able to take the code shown in the `changePageArray()` method and implemented for your use case. Add logic where needed, and maybe refresh changeDetection if it isn't propagating to the ui.

Hope this is what you were looking for, happy coding!

Comment: In my case it is not working as expected. still the grid loaded based on previous count.

Comment: Yeah I kept getting similar results until I explicitly modified the inputs of the paginator.pageSize:

this.paginator.pageSize = this.pageSizeOptions[0];


Not sure why this was the case, essentially the result of some trail and error coding